# Ionic Auth0 error: "Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of undefined"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, auth0, ionic3

I downloaded the example project from Auth0's [website](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic2). When I run the project with the `ionic serve` command the main page pulls up fine, but when I press login it throws the error `Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of undefined`. I have tried running this app on an Android device and it does work. Any ideas on how to fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: +1... I think it's not supposed to work on Browser. But just like you I am unable to run it on the app. Auth0 logs show that login was successful, but looks like the app is crashing during redirect after authentication.

Answer (score 2):

@cyberabis is correct in his comment.

`ionic serve` *does not load* cordova plugins.

Auth0 uses [auth0-cordova](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-cordova/) plugin which in turn requires:

- cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller
- cordova-plugin-customurlscheme

All these require you to run the ionic app in your device or emulator if you want to test the login functionality.

Comment: Hi Suraj, I am unable to get it working on mobile either. Auth0 log shows successful login, however, when redirecting inside the app, the app appears to crash and restart. Does it work for you? Do you happen to use Ionic 3 CLI?

Comment: you will have to debug and log errors.. no havent used ionic cli 3 but that seems unrelated here

Comment: I also had the same problem when running on my android device using, "ionic cordova run android --livereload". I dropped the "--livereload" portion and  it worked fine.

Comment: @MichaelBarce for some reason livereload or --c (consolelogs) option seems to disable cordova. May need to check with ionic devs about it

Comment: So we can't even test the app in the browser ever again after hooking up into auth0?

Comment: @emirhosseini you can use remote debugging feature in chrome or safari depending on your platform to see console logs